# Struggle in understanding maven depeendency scopes and classpaths

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Suppose this workflow of actions:

- I have my Eclipse maven project.
- I open the pom.xml, and add a dependency Dependency1 with a scope of "runtime"
- As soon as i save the pom.xml, eclipse will download the dependency from the central repository and put it in my local repository at .m2 folder.
- If i go on libraries/maven dependencies i will see this dependency with a green icon (which i imagine means it is not needed for compilation and if i try to import that class in any .java file i will get an error).
- As for the maven docs: "*This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath*."

  As soon as i write **import Depencency1.targetPackage.*;** i get ***the import "Dependency1 cannot be resolved"*** because i imagine "someone" is looking for the **Dependency1.jar** under a "path" (who defines that path) that does not contains it?!
  ***The abstract concept is clear to me but it'd like to know in depth what happens (and who makes it happen) from the moment i write an import statement into a .java file on eclipse to the point of "package cannot be resolved".***
- I'd also like to understand better (but I thinks this will come along with the understanding of the point above), how is this affecting the maven packaging process. For example I imagine that the JAR downloaded through a runtime dependency will not be physically included in the produced deliverable (JAR,WAR,EAR)?

Thanks for any helps, i'm looking many things around but really cannot find that complete explanation that fills all my doubts.

Davide

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies of scope `runtime` are packaged into the final WAR/EAR, but are not available for compilation. This scope is sometimes used if api and impl are separated into different jars. Then, marking the impl as `runtime` prevents you from accidentally using the classes from the impl.